# Internal Server Error (500) and PHP max_execution_time on Linux server

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I have a php script that need to be processed for one to 5 hours (sending newsletters to our customers). I tried both `set_time_limit(2000);` and `ini_set('max_execution_time', 360000);` but neither works. They work perfectly on the XAMPP local server, but they do not work on our dedicated server (Unix & Apache). I also changed the Apache timeout to 300 (which was 50), yet after 30 seconds of script running, it returns this:

> Internal Server Error Page (Error 500)

I have no idea if there is any other place for timeout and/or why the server does not honor the `ini_set()` or `set_time_limit()` functions. We are using Unix CentOS 6 and Plesk 11.9 as server. I also changed the default php.ini `max_execution_time`, and it works...

I read many articles and forums, yet I don't know why this happens. I appreciate your help.

Comment: just a suggestion, can you create a cron job?

Comment: scripts called from the command line have no time limit. you dont want a browser involved in this.

Comment: I suggest the cron tasks, get the package and send, mark this package as sent and next cycle, get next package and send, etc.

Comment: I suggest to try and split your sending into chunks, you'll be marked as a spammer so fast is not even funny.

Answer (score 1):

// add, in your php file header or config

```
ini_set('max_execution_time','256'); //max_execution_time','0' <- unlimited time
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

Good work!

Answer (score 0):

a better way would be using `ini_set()` or `set_time_limit()` at the top of the script which sends newsletters to the customers...you should not try to main config files...and also, as someone suggested above, cron jobs are good fit for such situations..

Comment: Hey guys, I appreciate your answers and comments. I setup the cron job, and it works perfect. I also have tried the chunk-chunk (150 emails per chunk) approach, and that one works too...

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your answers and comments. I setup the cron job, and it works perfect. I also have tried the chunk-chunk (150 emails per chunk) approach, and that one works too.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Vps:
Edit your php.ini file:

```
max_execution_time = 256
memory_limit = 512M
```

Then, run command line to restart apache

```
service httpd restart
```

Or header file

```
ini_set('max_execution_time','256');
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

Good luck!